# Computers communicating on same network

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, wcf

I'm trying to get two applications to communicate through a local network using HTTP / WCF. The Master makes web requests and looks for Slave applications that each has a web service running. The slaves are configured to answer to `localhost:\\[MACHINENAME]:8000`

It works when I run the slave on the same computer as the Master but not when I run it on another computer on the same network. I confirm that the computers are on the same network by the cmd prompt Ping [MachineName]. What is required to send requests to another computer on the same network?

Slave sets up webservice:

```
 public void Run()
        {
            Config config = Config.validateAndCreate();
            string machineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
            string baseAddress = "http://" + machineName + ":" + config.port;
            Service.setConfig(config);

            if (new Service().UpdateScripts().status != ExecStatus.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to update scripts");
            }

            using (WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress)))
            {
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
                host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

                ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");

                host.Open();
                log.Info("Service is running at: " + baseAddress);
                log.Info("Press the 'q' key to quit...");
                while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Q) { }
                host.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall (e.g. the in-built Windows firewall) running? That's the most likely thing to be stopping it.

Comment: I will check! Is there any way to tell if the firewall is blocking?

Comment: The easiest check is using web browser, if you are using http.

Comment: Ok! What should i expect in this case?

Comment: Ive added both Master and Slave to the allow through firewall list. 
I still dont get any communication neither through the application or the browser. I do get a service endpoint Endpoint not found when i try with the adress to the slave on the same computer. So i guess the slave works. Its just the master on the other computer that cant reach it. Only the master on the same computer.

Comment: @RB. You where right! It was the firewall. Thanks. Also i learned some good stuff from this thread. Do you want to make your comment into an answer so i can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Glad I could help - answer posted with a bit more detail :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely thing to be blocking it is a Firewall. If you haven't added a 3rd party firewall, then the Windows Firewall (which is on by default) will be blocking it.

You will need to add an exception to the firewall, to permit traffic on that port to be routed to your application.

Click "Start" and type "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security".

Click "Inbound Rules" -> New Rule, and add either a Program rule or a Port rule as appropriate.